# Fancybox Not working in IE8 giving [ Object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox']

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using `fancybox` for adding cart part of my website . `fancybox` works fine on Firefox, Chrome, and IE9 but not on IE8 . Really don't know why, please help.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".addToOrderButton").click(function(){
            $(".addToOrderButton").fancybox({
                'type'      : 'iframe',
                'width'     : '75%',
                'height'    : '75%',
                'autoScale'     : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'helpers'       : {overlay : { closeClick: false}},
                'href'          : 'includes/shopping_cart.php?drink_id='+$(this).attr("drink_id")

            });
        });

        $(".addToOrderButton").fancybox({
                 'type'     : 'iframe', 
            'width'     : '75%',
            'height'    : '75%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none'



        });
    });

</script>
<button drink_id="$drink->id" id="addToOrderButton_$drink->id" class="addToOrderButton" type="button" name="drink_add" value="Add" style="border: 0;cursor: pointer;background: transparent">
    <img src="./images/add_but.png" alt="submit" />
</button>
```

Comment: You aren't quoting your `drink_id` attribute correctly.

Comment: @Asad: Actually, there is a close quote on it, it's just the syntax highligher doesn't like the `>`. (The `>` is fine in a quoted attribute value in HTML, though.)

Comment: *"...IE8 giving [ Object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox']..."* What line is it reporting that error on? What happens if you walk through with the debugger (IE8 has a debugger, press F12 to open it).

Comment: Ya the line it shows up the error is $(".addToOrderButton").fancybox({

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah I didn't look at it closely enough, at first glance the text for the `id` attribute looked like it was part of the `drink_id` attribute.

Comment: I havent got any clue is the error coming up from my script or do i need to change any of the default fancybox properties in jquery.fancybox.pack.js file !!:(

Comment: is your script getting loaded in the browser? if you have developer tools, check in the network tab to find if the fancybox.js is loaded.

Comment: @user1897636: *"I havent got any clue is the error coming up from my script or..."* That's what debugging is for.

Comment: Whenever i debug it says , [Breaking on Jscript run time error : Object doesn't support property or method 'fancybox'

Comment: what version of fancybox? because you are mixing options for v1.3.4 and v2.x that are not compatible with each other.

Comment: @JFK fancybox version is 2.1.2 the latest one , and Jquery version is 1.8.3

Comment: I have tried to remove $(document).ready(function() { !! the pop up is coming up but it says " requested Content cannot be loaded"

Answer (score 5):

Thanx Alot everyone for your try , finally i have cracked it .

Replaced  $(document).ready(function() { with jQuery(function( $ ){

IE8 issue has been resolved ! Weird !!

Comment: Worked like a charm in ie9.